# Add attribute to element in a frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, frame

my question is: how I can select the element and add a attribute ( the element that I want to add the attribute is the h2#title ) in a frame.
the element will be selected in the main file.

main file - here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <frameset cols="100%" frameborder="0" class="test">
        <frameset rows="72, *">
            <frame src="head.html" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" name="headFrame" id="headFrame">
            <frame src="include.html" noresize="noresize" name="includeFrame" id="includeFrame">
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

head.html - this file is included by the main file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Header</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>LOGO</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

include.html - this file is included by the main file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Header</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="title">Wellcome</h2>
    <img src="images/1.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $("#includeFrame").contents().find("#title")

Comment: [Frameset and frame are deprecated since HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp). I would recommend using `iframe` instead, or better yet use a templating engine if that would work for your use case.

Comment: sure hope this isn't a new project using frames! ... it's 2015!

Comment: is not working James, I dont know why :(

Comment: [Documentation for accessing frames using vanilla JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames)

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
$("h2").attr("id", "title");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a script in the include.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Header</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="title">Wellcome</h2>
    <img src="images/1.jpg">
</body>
<script>
    $("#title").attr("style", "color:red;");
</script>
</html>
```

When the frame load the html file, the browser execute the script.